# How to filter elements of a list column

Tags: r, list, filter, purrr

I have a data frame (df) with 3 variables:

- ID (1st id variable)
- ID2 (2nd id variable)
- data (list column created with the tidyr::nest() function.

  ```
  library(tidyverse)
  library(lubridate)

  dates <- ymd(c('2018-02-01', '2018-02-06', '2018-02-10', 
                 '2018-02-21', '2018-04-05'))
  df.1 <- tibble(ID = paste0('ID_', rep(1, 5)),
             ID2 = LETTERS[1:5],
             DATE = dates) %>%
             group_by(ID) %>% 
             nest()


   df.2 <- tibble(ID = paste0('ID_', rep(1, 6)),
             ID2 = LETTERS[1:6])


   df <- df.1 %>%
   left_join(df.2, by = 'ID')
  ```

The list column (data) contains 2 variables:

- ID2
- DATE

I would like to keep all elements in the list column (`data[[DATE]]`) for which `data[[ID2]] != df$ID2`.

Is there any way to apply a filter function -- maybe of the purrr package?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: you can use `map`

Comment: When you say `data[[ID2]] != df$ID2` does it mean that the first element of `data[["ID2"]]` can be anywhere in `df$ID2`? And the same for the 2nd, 3rd, etc?

Comment: `Map(function(x, y){!x[["ID2"]] %in% y[["ID2"]]}, df$data, list(df))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas about your question OP should say the last word but that way all the data will be filtered out.

Comment: You should be more specific about the desired output but something like follow, filters out the rows that have `"A"` as their `ID2` in the nested column: `df %>% mutate(filtered = map(data, ~ filter(., ID2 != "A")))`

Comment: What I mean is a conditional rowwise filter. Example: When ID2 == 'A' (1st line, 2nd column), I would like to remove the first line of the tibble in the 3rd column of the data frame (data), because ID2 also equals 'A'. When ID2 == 'B' (2nd line, 2nd column), I would like to remove the 2nd line of the tibble in the 3rd column of the data frame (data), because ID2 also equals 'B'. And so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `map2`. We feed the list-column (`data`) as `.x` argument and `df$ID2` as `.y` argument and filter on each `.x` where `.x$ID2 != .y`:

```
library(tidyverse)

output <- df %>%
  mutate(data = data %>% map2(ID2, ~ filter(.x, ID2 != .y)))
```

**Output:**

```
> output
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  ID    data             ID2  
  <chr> <list>           <chr>
1 ID_1  <tibble [4 x 2]> A    
2 ID_1  <tibble [4 x 2]> B    
3 ID_1  <tibble [4 x 2]> C    
4 ID_1  <tibble [4 x 2]> D    
5 ID_1  <tibble [4 x 2]> E    
6 ID_1  <tibble [5 x 2]> F  

> output %>%
+   pull(data)
[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  ID2   DATE      
  <chr> <date>    
1 B     2018-02-06
2 C     2018-02-10
3 D     2018-02-21
4 E     2018-04-05

[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  ID2   DATE      
  <chr> <date>    
1 A     2018-02-01
2 C     2018-02-10
3 D     2018-02-21
4 E     2018-04-05

[[3]]
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  ID2   DATE      
  <chr> <date>    
1 A     2018-02-01
2 B     2018-02-06
3 D     2018-02-21
4 E     2018-04-05

[[4]]
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  ID2   DATE      
  <chr> <date>    
1 A     2018-02-01
2 B     2018-02-06
3 C     2018-02-10
4 E     2018-04-05

[[5]]
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  ID2   DATE      
  <chr> <date>    
1 A     2018-02-01
2 B     2018-02-06
3 C     2018-02-10
4 D     2018-02-21

[[6]]
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  ID2   DATE      
  <chr> <date>    
1 A     2018-02-01
2 B     2018-02-06
3 C     2018-02-10
4 D     2018-02-21
5 E     2018-04-05
```

Comment: Beautiful. I tried getting it right, but was on the `unlist()` route.